# How to control opacity of TextureBrush in GDI+

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am developing a MainForm as ActiveX control and I want to control TextureBrush opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Use a scaling color transform matrix, as described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, that scales the alpha channel to the level you want.

The example in that article has you use the ImageAttributes object with the color matrix set when drawing an image, but you can also pass an ImageAttributes object to the TextureBrush constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It's not possible to change the opacity of an existing TextureBrush object.